# Creating compound index on mongodb crashed centos

Tags: mongodb, crash, indexing, centos

I have one *MongoDB version 2.2.2-rc0* installed on *Centos 6.2* and there are 218 million records in the MongoDB. I want to create a compound index on these records to optimize the query.

But during creating the index on the collection, I experienced system crash several times so I have to reboot Centos. I just ignored the system crash and use my java code to access the data and unfortunately it doesn't work and I got the following error on MongoDB:

```
Tue Mar 26 16:33:09 [conn4] error: getFile() called in a read lock, yet file to return is not yet open
```

And my java program got the following error:

```
assertion src/mongo/db/database.cpp:257
```

I have checked line 257 of **database.cpp**, it seems that it has something to do with the read lock. But I am not a cpp programer so it is a bit difficult for me to drill into this. I am checking the syslog of Centos to find out why the OS crashes as well.

Any ideas on that error and what to do?